# function of a function (property) python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Python class with functions and properties like this:

```
@property
def xcoords(self):
    ' Returns numpy array. '
    try:
        return self.x_coords
    except:
        self.x_coords = self._read_coords('x')
        return self.x_coords

def _read_coords(self, type):
    # read lots of stuff from big file
    return array
```

This allows me to do this: `data.xcoords`, nice and simple.

I want to keep this as it is, however I want to define functions which allow me to do this:

```
    data.xcoords.mm
    data.xcoords.in
```

How do I do it?  I also want these function to work for other properties of the class such as `data.zcoords.mm`.

Comment: This should work as is, *if* you actually return a value from `_read_coords`.

Comment: how do you mean 'as is', where/in what way do I implement the mm/in functions?

Comment: Make `xcoords` an instance of a class that has properties `mm` and `in` defined using `@property`.

Comment: Looks like you need to add properties for `mm` and 'in` to the numpy array returned, either by subclassing the numpy array type or adding them to the instance object before it's returned.

Comment: I would like to keep `xcoords` a numpy array if possible.  what do you mean 'adding them to the object before it is returned'?

Comment: Sorry, guess it not possible to add properties to instances. That leaves you with subclassing (or duck-typing).

Comment: Hadn't seen the "return Numpy array" part. The problem of adding `mm` and `in` isn't actually related to the fact that you're defining a property. Note that you can't have an attribute called `in` because that's a keyword in Python.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want `xcoords` to return a `numpy` array, then people may not expect the value of `xcoords` to have `mm` and `in_` methods. You should think about whether `mm` and `in_` are really properties of the *arrays themselves*, or if they are properties of the class you're defining. In the latter case, I would recommend against subclassing `ndarray` -- just define them as methods of the containing class.

On the other hand, if these are definitely properties of the thing returned by `xcoords`, then subclassing `ndarray` is a reasonable approach. Be sure to get it right by defining `__new__` and `__array_finalize__` as discussed [in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

To decide whether you should subclass `ndarray`, you might consider whether you can see yourself reusing this class elsewhere in your program. (You don't *actually* have to use it elsewhere, right now -- you just have to be able to *see yourself* reusing it at some point.) If you can't, then these are probably properties of the containing class. The line of reasoning here is that -- thinking in terms of functions -- if you have a short function `foo` and  a short function `bar`, and know you will *never* call them any other way than `foo(bar(x))`, you might be better off writing `foo_bar` instead. The same logic applies to classes.

Finally, as larsmans pointed out, `in` is a keyword in python, and so isn't available for use in this case (which is why I used `in_` above).

Comment: I don't think your test for whether to subclass or not is definitive. Subclassing simply implies a specialization of the base class(es). All subclass instances are also instances of the base class, so nothing is lost, and other code that only knows about the base class should be able to use them just fine. What difference does it make it you'd reuse the class at some point?

Comment: @martineau, well, I agree that it isn't _definitive_ -- it was just a suggestion ("you might consider..."). It's more of a rough heuristic to tell whether you're creating a useful new class or useless clutter.

Comment: I don't see how it could be useless if you're actually using it. In my opinion something like this is a perfectly valid use of subclassing.